# Update all localizable.strings in project

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have approximately 15 languages in my app, so i have 15 files like this: localizable.strings(language name)

All they have one source, and difference is only in right part of expression.( Ex: "NoMoney" = "Free" in localizable.strings(English) and "NoMoney" = "Gratis" in localizable.strings(Italian)  and so on)

Is there any way to update all these files when I update source localizable file (It's localizable.strings(English) file )? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my project, I use [Twine](https://github.com/mobiata/twine) to maintain .strings files for many languages and it works pretty well. It allows to store translated strings for all languages in one "master" file and then generate appropriate .strings files for each language.